# CSS ::-webkit-scrollbar not working for javafx viewer

Tags: css

I tried css to customize the scrollbar in the java Swing embedded javafx webview, I use the same css for displaying two web pages, the scrollbar cannot be customized as expected as in css, but the other one can be customized very well, do anybody know if there is some limit on the web page display? Thanks! 
Html is the third party web page:

Here follows the css scripts:

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 120px !important;
    height: 120px !important;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollbar CSS is right but you put the wrong CSS in body and inner HTML.

```css
body{display: block;  overflow: auto; height: 1000px; width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box;}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px; height: 8px; background-color: red; }
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #000; }
```

```html
<body> 
this just test for scroll
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But what if my body element doesn't have a div, it might work or not? the webpage is third party, we could not add div in the body. I tried another webpage, the code works.

Comment: ok than put this style in body
body{display: block; overflow: auto; height: 1000px; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}
Remove that div element.

Comment: Now please check my answer again I re-edit and change code as per you want.

Comment: OK, I will test it later today, thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, I tested with the above code, but the scrollbar is not styles as expected, in my page, I have two scrollbars, one is the outer scrollbar, the other is the scrollbar in the table of the webpage. the table of the webpage can be styled, but the outer browser scrollbar cannot be styled. On the other hand, another webpage can be styled very well using the same code and same css.

Comment: This code only works in chrome and safari.
Please check proper CSS you put the same as I provided because it's working fine snippet than it's working perfectly on your page also.

Comment: I guess it might be an issue of javafx webengine load mechanism.I used javafx webview which supports webkit engine and css too.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with that.
Please check with this http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
It's very easy to integrate and also good for the custom scrollbar.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I wonder does javafx support this kind of jquery script? I am very new to the jquery. now I use javafx to display webpage in java swing application.